# Парсер файла TXT

Tags: php

имеется текстовый файл. Нахожу строку содержащую код, например UUDD. Нужно получить доступ к строкам RW между AP:

> AP;**ESTT**;VELLINGE;55.396111;13.025278;12
>   RW;03;55.396111;13.025278;12;0;030;030;2559
>   RW;21;55.396111;13.025278;12;0;210;210;2559
>   AP;**UUDD**;DOMODEDOVO;55.408611;37.906389;594
>   RW;14R;55.421061;37.872139;594;11010;135;135;11483
>   RW;32;55.396436;37.945803;594;11190;315;315;12467
>   RW;32L;55.395117;37.903344;594;10930;315;315;11483
>   RW;32R;55.399375;37.936464;594;0;315;315;77764
>   AP;**EKRS**;RINGSTED;55.425853;11.806822;115
>   RW;05;55.424042;11.802864;115;0;049;049;24052
>   RW;23;55.427664;11.810783;115;0;229;229;24052
>   AP;EKVD;VAMDRUP;55.425853;11.806822;115

```
$searchp = 'UUDD';

$content = file ('airports.txt');

foreach ($content as $full_line)

{
    $line = explode (';', $full_line);

    if ($line[1] == $searchp) {
    $result = $line[1];
```

Comment: Переносы строк как у вас в вопросе? Или же перенос строк только для нового AP?

Comment: нужны строки RW относящиеся к аэропорту UUDD. То есть до следующего кода аэропорта.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Прочитать файл в строковую переменную
2. Найти подстроку от `AP;UUDD` до `AP;`
3. Найти в этой подстроке подстроку от `RW;` до `RW;`
4. Сохранить найденные соответствия в массив

---

```
$ap_file = 'airports.txt';
$search = 'UUDD';

$content = file_get_contents($ap_file);
$need = preg_quote($search, '~');
$result = [];

if (preg_match_all("~(?<=AP;{$need}).+?(?=AP;)~s", $content, $arr)) {
    foreach ($arr[0] as $item) {
        if (preg_match_all('~RW;.+?(?=\s?RW;)~s', $item, $arr)) {
            $result[] = $arr[0];
        }
    }
}

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Вы бы мне помогли бы еще с последней строкой RW, не выводит последнюю строку по вашему коду, если там 3 выводит только 2, короче на одну меньше, подправьте пожалуйста!

Comment: Да, спасибо! кстати echo $result[2]; не выводит ничего.

Comment: @Oleg, замените второй шаблон на вот этот: `'~(?<=RW;).+?(?=\s)~s'`. На счёт `$result[2];` -- нужно учитывать структуру массива, т.к. он двухуровневый, то и обращаться к его элементам нужно так: `echo $result[0][2];`

Comment: Огромное спасибо за помощь! Всего вам хорошего!